# Using and declaring generic List<T>

Tags: java, list, generics, object, arraylist

So I'm working in Java and I want to declare a generic List.

So what I'm doing so far is `List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();`

But now I want to add in an element. How do I do that? What does a generic element look like?

I've tried doing something like List.add("x") to see if I can add a string but that doesn't work.

(The reason I'm not declaring a `List<String>` is because I have to pass this List into another function that only takes `List<T>` as an argument.

Comment: Have you tried passing it List<String> ?

Comment: See the documentation of the function that requires the `List<T>`, which will likely be a generic argument to the class it belongs to. You're likely the one defining what this `T` is somewhere in your own code.

Comment: T is not a concrete type, it is a generic type. can you paste the signature of "another function" ?

Comment: You can use `List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>()`  , and after you get an element by `get(int index)` downcast it to the desire class which compatible to *another function*.

Comment: @AlvinWong: Please don't advise to use raw types.

Comment: @URL87: No. He should use `List<String> list ...` (or whatever type he needs) and pass that to the generic method.

Comment: @flup && jlordo, I tried passing in a List<String> into the function but the compiler gave an error.

Comment: @jlordo : Sorry I meant to write `Object`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should either have a generic class or a generic method like below:

```
public class Test<T>  {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
    public Test(){

    }
    public void populate(T t){
        list.add(t);
    }
    public static  void main(String[] args) {
        new Test<String>().populate("abc");
    }
}
```

Comment: Or a generic thingy in the method declaration like `public <T extends SomeThing> T method(T arg)` (though that might be a more complicated case then OP currently has).

Comment: @akaIDIOT yepp, i did include `or generic method` in my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The T is the type of the objects that your list will contain.
You can write `List<String>` and use it in a function which needs `List<T>`, it shouldn't be a problem since the T is used to say that it can be anything.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add the "X"(String) into the list having type of  directly so that you need to write a function which accept T as a parameter and add into the List, like

```
List<T> myList = new ArrayList<T>(0);
public void addValue(T t){
  myList.add(t);
}
```

and while calling this function you can pass string.

```
 object.addValue("X");
```