# What does this mean when creating a MutableList? <Todo>

Tags: android, kotlin

This is a very noobie question, I apologise. So I'm just learning Kotlin, coming from JavaScript and while following a tutorial I saw this:

```
MutableList<Todo>
```

I understand a MutableList interface but what is `<Todo>` ? as in what is it called (e.g parameter, inheritance) so that I can find out more about what it means in the documentation, because to me i havent seen something like it (looks like XML?)

A link to where it is it explained would be fine, thanks in advance.

Comment: A `Carton<Egg>` would be a carton of eggs. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14355311/using-and-declaring-generic-listt

Comment: i see, so it is a declaration of the type. thank you for the link